# Using .sum() and += on std::valarray<T>

Tags: c++11, stl, containers, valarray

I am using the type `std::valarray<std::valarray<double>>` and wish to sum each of the contained valarrays element wise, to leave a `std::valarray<double>`.

The C++ documentation states that the operator .sum() can be applied to `std::valarray<T>` so long as the operator `+=` is defined for type T. My code below (method1) tries to apply this to `std::valarray<std::valarray<double>>`, but the result appears to be nonsense.

However if I perform this manually, using the `+=` operator (method2), I get the result I want. But the fact that method2 works seems to imply that the operator `+=` is defined for the type `std::valarray<double>`, and hence that method1, using .sum(). should work. I really can't understand what is happening here...

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

// Attempt to use .sum() operator
std::valarray<double> method1(const std::valarray<std::valarray<double>>& data) {
  return data.sum();
}

// Manual summation using += operator
std::valarray<double> method2(const std::valarray<std::valarray<double>>& data) {
  std::valarray<double> sum(data[0].size());
  for (size_t i{0}; i < data.size(); i++) {
    sum += data[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

// Display size and elements
void showData(const std::valarray<double> data) {
  std::cout << "Size = " << data.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "Data = ";
  for (size_t i{0}; i < data.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << data[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
  std::valarray<std::valarray<double>> data{{1,2},{3,4}};  
  showData(method1(data));
  showData(method2(data));
}
```

My output:

```
Size = 0
Data = 

Size = 2
Data = 4 6
```

Comment: This seems specific to some compiler, please specify which one you are using with which options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` method of `std::valarray` requires `operator+=` to be defined for its value type (in your case, `std::valarray`), but `std::valarray` also requires it to be default-constructible (from the "Numeric" concept requirement).
This allows the `sum` method to work without `operator+`, by first default-constructing an element, and then adding each contained element with `operator+=`.

Although it isn't defined anywhere, as far as I know, it probably works something like this.

```
T sum() const {
    T result;
    for (auto& it : elements) {
        result += it;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem with a valarray of valarrays (`std::valarray<std::valarray>`) is that a default-constructed valarray is empty. And when `operator+=` is applied with an empty valarray and a non-empty one, it results in undefined behavior (["The behavior is undefined if `size() != v.size()`"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith2)). What you are likely to get is an empty valarray as a result (but you could potentially get anything).

What you could use instead is [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). It requires an initial value as third parameter, which takes care of the problem.

```
std::accumulate(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::valarray<double>(data[0].size()))
```

[Live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b57a7a9937542da1)

PS: don't ask me why `std::valarray` has no method `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Indeed, compiling with `g++ -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` gives at runtime: "std::valarray<_Tp>& std::valarray<_Tp>::operator+=(const std::valarray<_Tp>&) [with _Tp = double]: Assertion '_M_size == __v._M_size' failed."